# Add hardcore div Masonry with infinite scroll

Tags: php, wordpress, html, jquery-masonry, infinite-scroll

I am using Masonry with Infinite Scroll for my dynamic projects.. Everything is working fine.. but when i insert a hardcore div in between dynamic div using if loop, that hardcore div is repeating every time when i scroll down.

**PHP CODE for inserting hardcore div :**

```
<?php
  global $con;
  $con = 0;    
?>
.
.
.
<?php
  if ($con==9) {    
?>
  <div id="post-<?php the_ID(); ?>99yi" <?php  post_class('thumb');?> style="border:none; margin-bottom:11px;">
    <div class="thumb-holder">
      The hardcore content comes here
    </div>
  </div>

<?php 
  }
?>
```

**The Javascript used for masonry infinite scroll :**

```
(function($){
            var $masonry = $('#masonry');

            $('#navigation').css({'visibility':'hidden', 'height':'1px'});

            $masonry.imagesLoaded( function(){
                $masonry.masonry({
                    itemSelector : '.thumb',
                    isFitWidth: true
                });
            });
        })(jQuery);

        jQuery(document).ready(function($){
            var $masonry = $('#masonry');

            $masonry.infinitescroll({
                navSelector : '#navigation',
                nextSelector : '#navigation #navigation-next a',
                itemSelector : '.thumb',
                loading: {
                    msgText: '',
                    finishedMsg: 'All items loaded',
                    img: 'http://www.abc.com/img/ajax-loader.gif',
                    finished: function() {},
                },
            }, function(newElements) {
                var $newElems = $(newElements).hide();

                $newElems.imagesLoaded(function(){
                    $('#infscr-loading').fadeOut('normal');
                    $newElems.show();
                    $masonry.masonry('appended', $newElems, true);
                });
            });

            $masonry.on('mouseenter', '.thumb-holder', function() {
                $(this).children('.masonry-actionbar').show();
            });

            $masonry.on('mouseleave', '.thumb-holder', function() {
                $(this).children('.masonry-actionbar').hide();
            });
        });
```

I have stuck in this issue.. Anyone have idea how to solve the issue.. Thanks for help in Advance.. :)